# Problem with on click function addition inside the svelte code. I am trying to implement the annotations for a specific text on the front end

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, svelte

I am currently working on implementing annotations in the Svelte framework. You can see the data structure I am working with in the code below. The visualization is working perfectly, with the content styled based on character indexes. However, I am facing a challenge in adding an 'on:click' function for user interaction. My difficulty arises from the fact that the entire styling is defined within the JavaScript function, and I need to loop through the annotations, considering their start and end indexes.

I would appreciate your help in adding the 'on:click' function so that I can integrate additional functionalities, such as modifying or deleting annotations when the user interacts with them. Does this approach seem suitable, or are there any errors? Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
<script>
  // @ts-nocheck
    
  let colorAnnotation = '#ff798090';
  let colorAnnotationText = '#ee456789';
    
  let annotatedData = {
    'text': `
    The sun hung low in the sky, casting long shadows across the quiet street. The sound of children playing echoed in the distance, and a gentle breeze rustled the leaves of the trees. It was a peaceful evening, perfect for a leisurely walk and some quiet reflection.
    
    As I strolled down the cobblestone path, the aroma of freshly baked bread wafted from a nearby bakery, tempting my senses. I couldn't resist stepping inside, where warm smiles greeted me, and I indulged in a warm baguette, still soft from the oven. With each bite, I felt a sense of contentment wash over me, savoring the simple pleasures of life on this serene evening.
    `,
    'annotations': [
        {
            'label': 'action',
            'start_offset': 23,
            'end_offset': 52,
        },
        {
            'label': 'comedy',
            'start_offset': 177,
            'end_offset': 206,
        },
        {
            'label': 'white',
            'start_offset': 272,
            'end_offset': 308,
        },
        {
            'label': 'location',
            'start_offset': 132,
            'end_offset': 166,
        },
        {
            'label': 'description',
            'start_offset': 313,
            'end_offset': 348,
        }
    ]
  };
    
  let formattedText = formatText(annotatedData.text, annotatedData.annotations);
    
  let isPopupMenuVisible = false;
  let popupMenuX = 0;
  let popupMenuY = 0;
    
  function popUpMenu(label, x, y) {
    // Here you can implement logic to show a pop-up menu
    // For this example, we'll just alert the label
    alert(`You clicked on: ${label}`);
    isPopupMenuVisible = true;
    popupMenuX = x;
    popupMenuY = y;
  }
    
  function formatText(text, annotations) {
    // Sort annotations by start_offset in ascending order
    annotations.sort((a, b) => a.start_offset - b.start_offset);

    let result = [];
    let lastIndex = 0;

    annotations.forEach(annotation => {
      const start = annotation.start_offset;
      const end = annotation.end_offset;

      // Text before the annotation
      result.push(text.substring(lastIndex, start));

      // Span for the annotation with Svelte on:click handler
      result.push(`
        <span style="background-color:${colorAnnotation}; cursor: pointer" on:click={() => popUpMenu('${annotation.label}', event.clientX, event.clientY)}
          >
          <span style="position:relative; background-color:white; color: ${colorAnnotationText};">${annotation.label}</span>
          ${text.substring(start, end)}
        </span>
      `);

      lastIndex = end;
    });

    // Text after the last annotation
    result.push(text.substring(lastIndex));

    return result.join('');
  }</script>
    
<div>
  {@html formattedText}
</div>
    
<div class="popup-menu" style="left:{popupMenuX}px; top:{popupMenuY}px; display: {isPopupMenuVisible ? 'block' : 'none'}">
    <!-- Add your pop-up menu content here -->
  <button on:click={() => isPopupMenuVisible = false}>Close</button>
</div>
    
<style>
  /* Define your styles here */
  .popup-menu {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index: 999;
    padding: 10px;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `on:event` in dynamically inserted HTML, that is Svelte-specific syntax that needs to be compiled.

Either use Svelte markup/separate components, or use event-bubbling to handle all annotation events on the parent element that is statically defined in Svelte.

If you want to use markup/a component you can pre-process your data into tokens and then use `#each` to render them instead of using `@html`. E.g.

```html
{#each tokens as token}
  {#if token.type == 'text'}
    {token.text}
  {:else if token.type == 'annotation'}
    <!-- Use button, otherwise accessibility sucks -->
    <button type="button" class="annotation"
            on:click={() => onAnnotationClick(token)}>
      {token.text}
    </button>
  ...
{/each}
```

For event delegation:

```html
<div on:click={onWrapperClick}>
  {@html formattedText}
</div>
```

```js
// when adding annotations
result.push(`
  <button type="button" ... data-annotation-id="${...}">
    ${text.substring(start, end)}
  </button>
`);

// handle clicks
function onWrapperClick(e) {
  const annotation = e.target.closest('[data-annotation-id]');
  if (!annotation)
    return;

  const id = annotation.dataset.annotationId;
  // [do stuff]
}
```

---

To remove default button styling, unset everything first:

```css
.annotation { all: unset; }
.annotation:focus-visible { outline: auto } /* restore focus display */
```